# Trying to boot into TWRP using fastboot gives the error FAILED (remote: unknown command)

Tags: twrp, fastboot

Using Razer phone on Android version 7.1.1. Bootloader unlocked.

This is how I go:

1. Enter bootloader.
2. Type `fastboot boot twrp.img`
3. Get following error:

```
C:\Users\SSD\Desktop\PATH\platform-tools>fastboot boot twrp.img
Downloading 'boot.img'                             OKAY [  0.649s]
booting                                            FAILED (remote: unknown command)
Finished. Total time: 0.659s
```

Comment: From what I've seen on XDA and Reddit, it seems Razer indeed disabled "fastboot boot" altogether. No way round.

Comment: But it fastboot boot worked when I was using the android 8.1 image

Comment: So? With a major Android version upgrade most OEMs would also update the bootloader partition. I won't be surprised if certain BL commands were enabled/disabled in the process (though the reasoning behind which is out of my speculation).

Comment: I already tried the instructions at the twrp website (https://twrp.me/razer/razerphone.html). It gives a similar error, that "remote: partition not found" and refuses to switch to slot b even after saying the slot was successfully switched.